# DataTable.Select ("Complete").Count<> is not giving correct total

Tags: c#, datatable

In my Winforms application Save button, I change the Complete column to true for the record I am saving, and later in the same button I get a total of records that are Completed (to be display on the screen):

```
dtFacilities.Rows[grdFacilities.CurrentCell.RowIndex].SetField ("Complete", true);
...
...
...
Completed = dtFacilities.Select ("Complete").Count<DataRow>();
```

When I look at the DataTable, I can see in my example right now that I have two records with that flag set to true.  One record was saved previously and one is the new record I just updated when they clicked the Save button.  However, Completed (an int) is coming back with 1.  The first time the user clicks the button, Completed is not updated.  After that first time not updating, it updates properly.

Does anyone see what I might be doing wrong?  I can supply more code if that will help.

[image]

This same line of code works perfectly in my load event:

```
Completed = dtFacilities.Select ("Complete").Count<DataRow>();
```

Just not in my Save method.

Comment: Weird, I cannot execute code like that. _Filter expression 'Complete' does not evaluate to a Boolean term._ Are you sure _Complete_ is of type int?

Comment: Nah, Complete is of type bool.  But that expression returns an int (the total).

Comment: Well, with the field defined as bool I got the right count. Something else then is happening   here.

Comment: Yeah, I think so, too.  Thanks for taking a look at it, Steve.

Comment: Should be something between setting the value and the reading (The ....)

Comment: On second thought. Did you try to write the full expression? _"Complete = true"_

Comment: I did.  About to paste a screenshot (if I can) that shows the data visualizer with a single "true" record, yet a count of 0 records.  Not sure how that can be.

Comment: Screenshot is in there now.  Data visualizer shows the true record,  yet the total still shows 0 records.

Comment: It looks like I somehow am losing track of the current row I am on.  Or that's my guess, anyway.  I don't usually work with DataGridViews in this manner.  What a mess I've got myself into. lol  Pasted the solution above.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I am losing track of the current row.  This was my original in that save button (before I actually got the total):

```
grdFacilities.Rows [grdFacilities.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells ["Complete"].Value = true;
dtFacilities.Rows [grdFacilities.CurrentCell.RowIndex].SetField ("Complete", true);
    
DataRow dr = dtFacilities.Rows.Find (grdFacilities.CurrentCell.Value);
dr ["Complete"] = true;
```

I found that if I reverse those lines, my totals work correctly:

```
DataRow dr = dtFacilities.Rows.Find (grdFacilities.CurrentCell.Value);
dr ["Complete"] = true;
 
grdFacilities.Rows [grdFacilities.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells ["Complete"].Value = true; 
dtFacilities.Rows [grdFacilities.CurrentCell.RowIndex].SetField ("Complete", true);
```

Comment: In theory you shouldn't need to update the Datatable if it is the DataSource of the DataGrid. Just calling EndEdit on the grid should be enough to transfer every change back to the DataTable.

Comment: Thanks, Steve.  I am a little new to binding.  I did not know that!